# Failing on apt-get update: The following signatures were invalid

Tags: ubuntu, apt, upgrade

Very recently when I have been attempting to check for updates on my laptop (Ubuntu 12.04), the check fails.

`sudo apt-get update`:

```
W: GPG error: http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise Release: The following signatures were invalid: BADSIG 40976EAF437D05B5 Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/i18n/Index  No Hash entry in Release file /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise_main_i18n_Index
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/multiverse/i18n/Index  No Hash entry in Release file /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise_multiverse_i18n_Index
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/restricted/i18n/Index  No Hash entry in Release file /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise_restricted_i18n_Index
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/universe/i18n/Index  No Hash entry in Release file /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise_universe_i18n_Index
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

`/etc/apt/sources.list` (comments removed):

```
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise main restricted
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise main restricted

deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates main restricted
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates main restricted

deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise universe
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates universe
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates universe

deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates multiverse

deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security main restricted
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security universe
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security multiverse
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security multiverse

deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu precise partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu precise partner

deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main
deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ precise partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ precise partner
```

I'm not sure how to solve the issue and appreciate any input.

Comment: Not sure how this would translate into Ubuntu but I had a similar problem with Debian when my repos were pointing to `squeeze`. As `wheezy` was released, the Debian 6 repos were no longer called `squeeze` but `oldstable`. Maybe it's the same problem here and your repos are referring to a release by its codename. What does your `/etc/apt/sources.list` contain?

Comment: @JosephR. It's worth a shot.  I added the contents of `/etc/apt/sources.list` to my post

Comment: OK you're on Precise Pangolin, it seems, which is an LTS release so obviously this is not the problem...

Comment: On closer inspection of the error messages, have you tried removing the problematic files from `/var/lib/apt/lists/partial` ? Although removing them should be harmless, don't actually remove them, just rename them and try again. It may be that your apt cache got botched somehow.

Comment: @JosephR. I renamed the files and it got rid of all but the first error. I tried choroba's solution afterward to attempt to remove the first error with no success

Comment: For myself, I had a PPA in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` that no longer existed and so this error was coming up. I had to remove that (actually, replace it with an updated repo for `ffmpeg` that I needed) and then `sudo apt-get update` worked just fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a little more searching I have found [the solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/198371/apt-encounters-errors-with-bad-gpg-keys).

Remove/Rename the files associated with the errors:

```
cd /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/
sudo mv us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise_main_i18n_Index main_COPY
sudo mv us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise_multiverse_i18n_Index multi_COPY
sudo mv us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise_restricted_i18n_Index res_COPY
sudo mv us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise_universe_i18n_Index uni_COPY
```

Update the signature:

```
gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv 40976EAF437D05B5
```

Rebuild the software cache:

```
cd /var/lib/apt
sudo mv lists lists.old
sudo mkdir -p lists/partial
sudo apt-get update
```

It is probably possible to skip the first step by simply moving the lists, but I figured it best to describe the entire process I used to remove the errors.

Comment: If you need to get the `40976EAF437D05B5` part, you can do an `apt-get update`.  When that fails and errors out, the key identifier should be listed in that output.

Answer (score 3):

Try importing a new key:

```
gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv 40976EAF437D05B5
gpg --export --armor 40976EAF437D05B5 | sudo apt-key add -
```

Comment: I tried your solution but did not have any success; I still receive the same errors.  Although when I ran the first command, I found this in the output: `gpg: no ultimately trusted keys found`

Comment: This solution worked for me. Don't forget to replace the guid with your own (i.e. 40976EAF437D05B5)